# Need to merge multiple json into single json in neo4j using cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I want to merge multiple json into single json in cypher.
LocalizationKey is parent node and all languages is his child node.

I want to merge all child node into single json in cypher.

I have return cypher query to fetch the data as expected below

```
MATCH (key:Key)-[*1]->(languages)
WITH key, collect(languages) as Languages
return apoc.map.setKey( key, 'Languages', Languages ) as LocalizationValue
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "localizationKey": "P2P_CM_BasicDetails",
  "Languages": [
    {
      "en_US": "Basic details",
      "cz_CZ": "Základní údaje",
      "de_DE": "Grundlegende Details",
      "en_AU": "Basic Details"
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently getting result as:

```
{
  "localizationKey": "P2P_CM_BasicDetails",
  "Languages": [
    {
      "en_US": "Basic details"
    },
    {
      "cz_CZ": "Základní údaje"
    },
    {
      "de_DE": "Grundlegende Details"
    },
    {
      "en_AU": "Basic Details"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please point to a gist with your data.

I'd like to try a second WITH with a new collect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
MATCH (key:Key)-->(lang)
WITH key, REDUCE(s={}, x IN COLLECT(lang) | apoc.map.merge(s, x)) AS Languages
RETURN apoc.map.merge(key, {Languages: Languages}) AS LocalizationValue
```

uses `apoc.map.merge` to merge maps, and returns a result in the following format (which is what I think you *actually* want, since it does not make sense for `Languages` to be a list containing just a single object):

```
{
  "localizationKey": "P2P_CM_BasicDetails",
  "Languages": {
    "en_AU": "Basic Details",
    "cz_CZ": "Základní údaje",
    "en_US": "Basic details",
    "de_DE": "Grundlegende Details"
  }
}
```